# Unknown JavaScript syntax when defining an object

Tags: javascript

I came across some JavaScript syntax I haven't seen before. Can someone help point me in the right direction, I'm not even sure what I could google to learn more :/

```
$.variable = function() {
  return a(b, [{
    key: "setPeriod",
    value: function(t) {
      this.variable.period = t;
    }
  }, {
    key: "location",
    get: function() {
      return "earth";
    }
  }])
}

$.variable.setPeriod("test");
$.variable.location;
```

My question is what is this structure where an object is defined via a list. Also not sure what the difference between `value` and `get` is. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's an example of a snippet:
https://pastebin.com/zymW2XZw

Comment: Looks like a pair of brackets - `()` - is missing. Did you copy-paste ?

Comment: By the way could you include the definition of `a` and `b` please ?

Comment: It's not a copy/paste, i tried to show a simplified version of what was going on. I've included a snippet of the code I was looking at in the original question.

Comment: Could you share the line number please ? x-D

Comment: On line 13 you can seen the `return` statement which returns the output of the function `s` which includes an array of objects all of which include the `key` and `value` fields.

Comment: Your example is misleading, you should better forget it as soon as possible. The fact that the original code relies on a framework called React and has been compressed (variables renamed with a single letter) makes it hard to know what happens to this list of objects, but we can easily imagine that it's processed by the `s` function and transformed into something else before being used.

Comment: Unfortunately it was minified :( This particular snippet included clear associations with React, but others didn't so I wasn't sure if it was something React specific.

Comment: In your edited post, `$.variable` is a function that returns the result of calling `a`.  We don't know what `a` does. We don't know what `b` might be.  Both `key` and `get` are property/method names of the object they are declared in.  Since a function is also an object, it can have methods and properties such as 'setPeriod` and `location`, which have not been described.  What is there not to understand, where is the syntax you have never seen before?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter whether it's minified or not, all you need to know is that there is no specific feature involved in such a code structure, only an list of objects that is translated into another object by a function called `s`. No matter why and how, you are supposed to let `s` do its job and simply use the resulting object :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my guess about what happens to this list of objects :

```js
var o = s([{
  key: "attribute",
  value: "default"
}, {
  key: "getAttribute",
  value: function () {
    return this.attribute;
  }
}, {
  key: "setAttribute",
  value: function (value) {
    this.attribute = value;
  }
}]);

console.log(o.getAttribute());
o.setAttribute("custom");
console.log(o.getAttribute());

function s (members) {
  var o = {};
  members.forEach(function (member) {
    o[member.key] = member.value;
  });
  return o;
}
```

I guess the framework needs to preprocess the object's members for some obscure reasons related to the framework internal mecanism.

Comment: Hey @leaf thanks for the patience. This question was kind of a shot in the dark. I was hoping someone would recognize what's going on here and shed some light on it. It's difficult to find the functions that are doing the transformations because it was minified and all the functions and variables were renamed and were often reused depending on the context. I appreciate the guess. Especially because it works, I'm accepting this answer. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome @Rawr, ask if you have more questions :-)